# How to mock static closures in Groovy/Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, spock

I'm trying to unit ( not integration) test a piece of legacy code that I can't change:

```
class Job {
 public boolean isStale(String param) {
     def status
     StatusObj.withTransaction {
        status = StatusObj.findByJobIdAndParam(getId(), param)
     }
     return status
 }
}
```

and here is my attempt to Stub it:

```
 def  () {
        setup:        
        GroovySpy(StatusObj, global: true)       
        StatusObj.withTransaction(_) >> StatusObj
        StatusObj.findByJobIdAndParam(_,_) >> 2


        when:
        def isStale = job.isStale("test")
        then:
        isStale == 2
    }
```

I can't figure out how to get to the inner mock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Unroll
class JobSpec extends Specification {
    def "spec"() {
        when:
        GroovySpy(StatusObj, global: true)
        def job = new Job(id: "ID")
        def param = "test"
        1 * StatusObj.withTransaction(_) >> { Closure action ->
            action.call()
        }
        1 * StatusObj.findByJobIdAndParam(job.id, param) >> status

        then:
        job.isStale(param) == isStale

        where:
        status | isStale
        0      | false
        1      | true
        2      | true
    }
}
```

Here `action` is your `status = StatusObj.findByJobIdAndParam(getId(), param)` from `Job` class. How it works can be found in sections [Computing Return Values](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_computing_return_values) and [Performing Side Effects](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_performing_side_effects) of Spock documentation. Also, note that I've made `Job.getId()` work by adding `id` field to `Job` class. I'm not sure how it's implemented in your code

Answer (score 1):

The *findByJobIdAndParam* takes 2 args:

```
status = StatusObj.findByJobIdAndParam(getId(), param)
```

Your stub takes 1 arg:

```
StatusObj.findByJobIdAndParam(_) >> 2
```

Try changing the stub like that:

```
StatusObj.findByJobIdAndParam(_, _) >> 2
```